# Need hints for Inequality question

Tags: real-analysis

Can someone give me some hints for proving that $∀\varepsilon >0, x+\varepsilon > t\Rightarrow x\geq t$? I really don’t know how to start with. Thanks

Comment: Let $x+\epsilon>t$ for all $\epsilon >0$ but assume (for contradiction) that $x<t$.

Comment: try this question:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438477/discrete-mathematics-x-leq-y-epsilon-implies-x-leq-y

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Suppose $x < t$, then $t-x > 0$.